# How to put 6 same sized JButtons into JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to put into my JPanel 6 JButtons in such a way that there will be 3 JButtons in one line and beneath another 3 JButtons. Since I know that explicitly JPanel works with Flow Layout Manager, I got such an idea:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

JButton button1 = new JButton();
JButton button2 = new JButton();
JButton button3 = new JButton();
JButton button4 = new JButton();
JButton button5 = new JButton();
JButton button6 = new JButton();

button1.setSize((panel.WIDTH)/3,(panel.HEIGHT)/2);
button2.setSize((panel.WIDTH)/3,(panel.HEIGHT)/2);
button3.setSize((panel.WIDTH)/3,(panel.HEIGHT)/2);
button4.setSize((panel.WIDTH)/3,(panel.HEIGHT)/2);
button5.setSize((panel.WIDTH)/3,(panel.HEIGHT)/2);
button6.setSize((panel.WIDTH)/3,(panel.HEIGHT)/2);

panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);
panel.add(button3);
panel.add(button4);
panel.add(button5);
panel.add(button6);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, I can not succeed in changing the size of the button. Does anybody have an idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: Why don't you use `GridLayout`?

Comment: setSize() specifically works *only* if you do not use a layout manager. Guess what the layout manager does when it places your components? It simply overwrites the size you have set manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- this is job for [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
- override `getPreferredSize` for [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)
- call `JFrame.pack();` before `JFrame.setVisible(true);`
- see [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `GridLayout` for that, if you want more control you can also use `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use any layout manager, then first make `frame.setLayout(null)` and also use `button1.setBounds(x,y,width,height)` for every button instead of `setSize()`. Lastly  `frame.setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out some other Layouts, such as the `GridLayout`, or the `GridBagLayout`.
[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), from Oracle, might prove useful.

However, when working with Layouts, use `setPreferredSize(Dimension size)`, instead of `setSize`.

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` is a good idea but if you don't plan to add more components to the panel or only in group of 3, [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) with its `makeGrid` methods would do the trick too.